# How to use <b-img-lazy> in bootstrap vue card

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

```
<b-card overlay
  :title="name"
  :sub-title="subtitle"
  :img-src="cardImg"
  img-top
  style="max-width: 20rem;"
  class="mb-2 insider-image"
  ref="card">
</b-card>
```

I'm currently rendering a huge file of image to my card's background. How can I use the `b-img-lazy` insider the card

Comment: You mean you want the card's background image to load lazily?

Comment: @jom there's already a component in bootstrap vue that does lazy loading which is <b-img-lagzy> but if this is not usable within card, then yes how can I load images lazily?

Comment: I'm sure you have tried putting this `<b-img-lazy>` component inside of the `<b-card>`, but didn't that work?

Comment: I can add the `<b-img-lazy>` inside `<b-card>` but it's not treating as the background image of the card. it treats as a content.

Comment: Looks like you're gonna need to implement this feature yourself, have a look at [this post](/a/13655739/3634538). It's for jQuery, but the point is you just need to add a listener on `load` event.

Answer (score 4):

Use the new `b-card-img-lazy` sub-component.  You will still need to manually place the sub-component inside `<b-card no-body>` and palce any additional sub components needed to build up the cafrd (i.e. `<b-card-body>`, etc).

Refer to the "Kitchen Sink" example of the `b-card` docs page.  it shows placing a regular `<b-card-img>` sub-component, which could be changed to a `<b-card-img-lazy>` sub-component.